# Get SQL array as checkboxes

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

I have a form that saves each item to my database. I have checkboxes for the different options such as category and sub category which saves as an array. All of that works perfectly when saving into the database. But I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the checkboxes ticked if the category is wrong. I have tried numerous things and have finally just given up. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

On my edit page I have two blocks of code: one that GETs the info from the database and one that POSTs the updated information.

Here's the GET code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['sid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['sid'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scents WHERE id='$targetID' LIMIT 1");
    $scentCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($scentCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

             $scent_name = stripslashes($row["scent_name"]);
             $can_compat = $row["can_compat"];
             $gel_compat = $row["gel_compat"];
             $scent_description = stripslashes($row["scent_description"]);
             $sug_color = stripslashes($row['sug_color']);
             $soap_compat = $row["soap_compat"];
             $phthalate_free = $row["phthalate_free"];
             $category = stripslashes($row["category"]);
             $subcategory = stripslashes($row["subcategory"]);

        }
    } else {
        $msg_to_user = "Sorry, That scent doesn't exist.";
    }
}

?>
```

Here's the POST code:

(I do not have category and sub category checkoxes being updated because I can't get them to work, so will add that when I can figure it out)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['scent_name'])) {
    $sid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
    $allowed = '<div><p><span><strong><em><br><a><img><h1><h2><h3><h4><ul><ol><li><blockquote>';
    $scent_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['scent_name']);
    $scent_description = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['scent_description'], $allowed));
    $can_compat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['can_compat']);
    $gel_compat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gel_compat']);
    $soap_compat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['soap_compat']);
    $phthalate_free = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phthalate_free']);
    $sug_color = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sug_color']);

if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
    $category = implode(", ", $_POST['category']);   
        } else {
            $category = "";
        }

if(isset($_POST['subcategory'])) {
    $subcategory = implode(", ", $_POST['subcategory']);   
        } else {
            $subcategory = "";
        }

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `scents` SET `scent_name`='$scent_name', `scent_description`='$scent_description', `can_compat`='$can_compat', `gel_compat`='$gel_compat', `soap_compat`='$soap_compat', `phthalate_free`='$phthalate_free', `sug_color`='$sug_color' WHERE `id`='$sid'");

    header("location: admin_scent_manage.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Here's the some of the form code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Holidays: <label for="category">
        <input type="checkbox" id="category[]" name="category[]" value="Holiday" >
        </label>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Christmas" > Christmas<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Valentines" > Valentines Day<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Thanksgiving" > Thanksgiving<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="StPatrick\'s" > St. Patrick's Day<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Easter" > Easter<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="4th" > Fourth of July<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Wedding" > Wedding<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Mother\'s Day" > Mother's Day<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="subcategory[]" name="subcategory[]" value="Father\'s Day" > Father's Day
     </td>
   </tr>
```

I need to figure out how to make sure the correct checkboxes are checked if a certain category or subcategory is in the array for the particular item, and so that if I need to uncheck them or check other boxes it is updated accordingly. Everything else updates perfectly fine. I just can't figure out the checkboxes part. I have tried everything I could find and nothing has worked so I just have them not updating right now.

Comment: What if for each checkbox input, you check to see if `mysql_num_rows() > 0` on a query selecting all rows with the subcategory value?

Comment: how a category can be wrong?either it is chosen either no...explain

Comment: How can a category be wrong?

Comment: The category isn't wrong, I am trying to figure out if the category "holiday" is actually in the field then it ticks the check box, but if it is not in the field then the box is not ticked.